# Ternary operator - unexpected behavior

Tags: php

I have a Product class which retrieves database data by the product name. The URL would look like this:

```
/products/product-name
```

My class works fine and retrieves product data when this method is function is executed:

```
$library->get('Router')->map('GET|POST', '/products/[*:product]', function($prod) use ($library){
    require_once(_DIR_ . 'lib/Product.php');
    $p = new Product($prod);
    $state = $p->prepare();
    require_once(_DIR_ . $state ? "views/product.php" : "views/404.php");
});
```

Only, when the `$state` is false, the required file is the product.php file not the 404.php file.

I have debugged this and the `$state` IS false when there is no product so my method is returning the correct bool, only, the ternary operator seems to run the TRUE each time.

If I change the expression to this:

```
require_once(_DIR_ . $state === TRUE ? "views/product.php" : "views/404.php");
```

It works fine, can someone explain why this is happening? If I was to do:

```
$example = false;
echo ($example) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

It works, so why is it behaving this way?

Also,

```
require_once(_DIR_ . $p->prepare() === TRUE ? "views/product.php" : "views/404.php");
```

Does not work, this runs false everytime...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ternary operator left associativity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559150/ternary-operator-left-associativity)

Comment: Oh, that actually makes so much sense now... the `_DIR_` needs to be separate from the expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.` has [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) over the ternary operator, you need to use parentheses:

```
require_once(_DIR_ . ($state ? "views/product.php" : "views/404.php"));
```

Comment: this worked, it makes more sense now! Didn't know that it did it like that

Answer (score 2):

In the first   `require_once(_DIR_ . $state ? "views/product.php" : "views/404.php");`  you don't eval  a condition so the ternary not return the proper value

In the second

```
require_once(_DIR_ . $state === TRUE ? "views/product.php" : "views/404.php");
```

you clearly test a valid condition and the ternary operator can work correctly

```
 _DIR_ . $state
```

is not a condition is an assertion

Answer (score 2):

> Only, when the $state is false, the required file is the product.php
>   file not the 404.php file.

But you're not testing just `$state`, you're testing the result of the concatenation of `_DIR_` and `$state`.

Since `_DIR_` will always return a truthy value, the collective result is never false.

This is not your intention, of course; as @trincot notes, the `_DIR_` reference is part of the require path, not the condition. So use parentheses to distinguish the two:

```
require_once(_DIR_.($state ? "views/product.php" : "views/404.php"));
```