# How nested ternary operator in PHP works?

Tags: php, conditional-operator

```
echo $verified == 0?'Unverified':$verified == 2?'Shortlisted':'Verified'
```

Expected output when $verified = 0 is `Unverified` but it actually echo `Shortlisted`. After few tries, I did:

```
echo $verified == 0?'Unverified':($verified == 2?'Shortlisted':'Verified')
```

And it worked! I was just curious how exactly this is executing if anyone knows. I tried this in C language the result was `Unverified` that's why I'm especially tagging PHP.

This might sound an improper question for community but I wasn't able to find any article regarding this.

Comment: This should answer your question: [Ternary operator left associativity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559150/ternary-operator-left-associativity). In PHP it has an associativity different from every other language. Anyway I upvoted your question because it made me learn something new.